# Get content from span with no class?

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

I got some HTML that reads `<span class=""...></span>`

I want to use JSoup to get what is between these two tags, but I only have one other identifier on those span classes, and it's `<...attr="?"...></span>`

The ? is an auto generated number starting at 0. How would I go about getting the content in the span tag? I seem to have few choices in identifiers.

Comment: Get all the spans, then check for `spanElement.attr("yourAtribut")` ?

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. I am fairly new to JSoup. Will try it.

Comment: you should check the jsoup cookbook: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Answer (score 2):

Use an attribute selector, where `attr` is the name of the attribute. You can leave out the attribute value if you're not interested in it, and you can pretty much ignore the `class` attribute altogether:

```
Element span = doc.select("span[attr]").first();
String spanText = span.text();
```